# Does Amazon SNS mobile push notification service use xmpp for GCM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

The question already tells itself, i have been searching for a while if amazon sns mobile push notification service uses xmpp(CCS) or not ?

Does anyone know the right answer ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SNS provides an abstraction, so whether it uses HTTP or CCS doesn't really matter, as the functionality is defined and controlled by the API that Amazon exposes. With that said, I think the answer is no. I am fairly certain Amazon SNS communicates with GCM over HTTP and not using XMPP.